# SQLServer nchar and .Net unicode with special F801 charcter

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have an existing database with existing data that I can't change it's structure or values.
In that database there is a nvarchar column that contains values in the twilight unicode zone starting with F800, upward.
When I select those values in SQL or use SQL function, unicode - I get the proper values.
When I select the same values in .Net - I get an error value - all the values in that twilight zone become 65533.
I need those values - how can I presuade .Net to give me those values - something like chaninging the connection encoding to a custom one - or ucs-2 etc...

Here is a sample code that demonstraits the problem:

```
c.CommandText = "select NCHAR(55297)";
using (var r = c.ExecuteReader())
{
   r.Read();
   var result = r[0]; //expected 55297 but got 65533
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigations I failed to find any way around this. I couldn't find any two way conversion that would work here.

It seems that some unicode values are intended for some strange unicode scenario that isn't supported by .Net, but is partially supported in a way that breaks what we need here.

Answer (score 1):

55297 is D801 which isn't defined? you probably want f801 which is 63489? But it appears as if that one isn't defined either. Which characters do you want?

If I try doing a "select NCHAR(55297)" in SQL Server Management studio, I get back the diamond question mark, but if I do "select NCHAR(63489)" I get back a dot of some sort: 

If what you want is the character values, you can ask for them directly:

```
select Unicode(NCHAR(63489))
```

This returns 63489 (as an integer)

If you want them as a byte array, you can ask for that:

```
select CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), FieldThatIsAnNvarchar) from ThatTable
```

Comment: Hi, I need all of them. The fact that there are characters that are stored in the database and I get them as garbage is problematic for my application.
I have a user that translated an encrypted byte array and stored it in the nvarchar column. Not being able to get the 2040 chars that .Net doesn't return for me, causes the decryption algorithm to return invalid results.

Comment: @Noam So, I think this is because the "characters" aren't really characters. If they've been encrypted, they probably aren't unicode characters? They're just random bytes. So, treat them as bytes?

Comment: Yep. Seems like `varbinary` would be more suitable.

Comment: @Noam: use `VARBINARY(MAX)` to store bytes. Strings are not bytes, and a programmer should know as much... http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Noam I just added a binary work around. Read it as bytes from the database.

Comment: @McKay, I see your solution, and that's one way to go.
Still I'm looking for a solution in .Net itself, setting some property to the connection or something. Some times I get the SQL as a predefined sql, that I can't change.

Comment: @Noam Check this out:
select case when NChar(55297) = NCHAR(55298) then 1 else 0 end
The data is already (mostly) lost

Comment: @McKay I see, but still, my problem still exists. It's one thing to explain to my customer why it isn't working, it's much better to get it to work. The tool he was using to insert the data can extract it, thus accepting that .net can't extract it is not trivial

Comment: @RemusRusanu, I agree completely about what programmers should know.
And in a theroertical world where I have control over everything - you would be correct.
Unfortunately - in my real world - the current situation is a fact that I have to handle.

Comment: @Noam Well, first off, you aren't giving us very much detail. Are you really selecting `select NCHAR(55297)`? If his tool is working? What language is it in? What queries is it using?

Comment: @McKay - Sorry for not providing enough detail.
The tool he is using is called magic. It's an obsolete development platform (like power builder etc...).
The data is stored in an ntext column.
I'm selecting it from a data access layer that generates the sql's for it on the fly.
I can create a different sql as you suggested - I was hoping for something within .Net, and not affect the SQL itself. Either change the encoding object for the connection, or get the original bytes from the unicode column in the db (I saw it when I dove in with debug through the object, but ut's very private)

Comment: @Noam So the way I see it is that you've got this cascade of problems:  The content is stored incorrectly in the database (binary data in nvarchar), the queries are written by code which is constrained to the wrong type, and so the data can't be written. One of the layers has to change.

Comment: @McKay - I agree, I was hoping that it could only be my layer. The .Net layer that reads the result of the SQL.